# Why does datadog lambda instrumentation return a `datadog-lambda-js/handler.handler is undefined or not exported`?

Tags: node.js, logging, aws-lambda, datadog

The Datadog AWS Lambda instrumentation seems unreliable to me. Every few invocations, I get the following error:

```
    "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
    "errorMessage": "/opt/nodejs/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/handler.handler is undefined or not exported",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: /opt/nodejs/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/handler.handler is undefined or not exported",
        "    at HandlerNotFound.ExtendedError [as constructor] (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/runtime/errors.js:113:28)",
        "    at new HandlerNotFound (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/runtime/errors.js:131:42)",
        "    at load (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/runtime/user-function.js:151:15)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/handler.js:65:59)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
        "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)",
        "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)"
    ]
}
```

To start the instrumentation, I run the following code.

```
datadog-ci lambda instrument \
   -f my-lambda-name \
   -r my-region \
   -v 50 -e 15 \
   --service my-service \
   --env my-env \
   --version 1.0
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the runtime environment, you should point to a different version of the datadog layer extensions.

Python, for example, uses `-v 50 -e 15`, but Node.js handlers should use a different version, `-v 66 -e 16`.

All of this is available in the documentation: https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/installation/nodejs/?tab=datadogcli